# Obtener elementos de una tabla que no esté en otra SQL Server

Tags: sql

Intento resolver lo siguiente:
Obtener los proveedores que no se le ha asignado un codigo, todos los proveedores que estén en cat_proveedores y no en cat_articulos

Cat_articulos contiene: numcodigo y num proveedor

Cat_proveedores: numproveedor y nomproveedor

Mi solucion es la siguiente:

```
select nomproveedor from cat_proveedores
left join cat_articulos on
cat_proveedores.numproveedor = cat_articulos.numproveedor
where cat_articulos.numproveedor is null
```

me trae resultados pero no estoy seguro sea correcta la query

Comment: Para la validación que buscas, es importante que tu ejemplo tenga datos de prueba y la salida que esperas. CUalquier consulta es correcta dependiendo de para qué la uses :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma simple es traducir: *todos los proveedores que estén en cat_proveedores y no en cat_articulos* a un patrón que se lo suele conocer como `anti join`:

```
select numproveedor, 
       nomproveedor
       from Cat_proveedores
       where numproveedor not in (select distinct numproveedor 
                                         from cat_articulos)
```

Comment: El distinct es innecesario ya que SQL Server lo hace por default al usar IN o EXISTS.

Comment: @LuisCazares, es bueno tu comentario, lo sé, en efecto para el resultado final es innecesario. El uso del  `distinct` en este caso, es más una cuestión de práctica ya que facilita la eventual constatación de los resultados obtenidos de la subconsulta.